# Scala SymbolMatcher failing to match import prefix

Tags: scala, scalameta, scalafix

I'm using the scalafix library to try to convert a project from scalaz to cats, but one particular attempt at removing imports (the first case in the following code) is failing. The relevant bits of code are:

scalafix code:

```
package fix

import scala.meta._
import scalafix.v1._

class MigrateList extends SemanticRule("MigrateList") {
  private lazy val std = SymbolMatcher.normalized("scalaz.std.list")
  private lazy val syntax = SymbolMatcher.normalized("scalaz.syntax.std.list")

  override def fix(implicit doc: SemanticDocument): Patch =
    doc.tree.collect {
      case Importer(
          syntax(_),
          List(ip @ Importee.Name(Name("ToListOpsFromList"))),
          ) =>
        Patch.removeImportee(ip)
      case Importer(
          std(_),
          List(ip @ Importee.Name(Name("listInstance"))),
          ) =>
        Patch.removeImportee(ip)
    }.asPatch
}
```

input file:

```
package fix

import scalaz.std.list.listInstance
import scalaz.syntax.std.list.ToListOpsFromList

object MigrateList {}
```

expected output:

```
package fix

object MigrateList {}
```

actual output:

```
package fix

import scalaz.syntax.std.list.ToListOpsFromList

object MigrateList {}
```

It's the `syntax(_)` part of the pattern that's the issue. Replacing that with a wildcard causes match to succeed and the import to be removed.
Printing the value of what's there when it matches shows `scalaz.syntax.std.list`.
Replacing the pattern with

```
Term.Select(
  Term.Select(
    Term.Select(Name("scalaz"), Name("syntax")),
    Name("std"),
  ),
  Name("list"),
)
```

works too, so I'm pretty sure I'm attempting to match the right thing, just using the SymbolMatcher wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was assuming that the tree and its associated symbol were structured the same way, with the symbol simply adding metadata.
Actually, the AST is the same as what I was using, but when the `SymbolMatcher` runs its `unapply`, it finds that for syntax imports, their path actually gets "resolved" through `scalaz.syntax.std.package.list`.